# How to get a list of cookies a website sets

Tags: javascript, php, web, cookies

So i am trying to understand a simple web application i saw last week. I wanna code a little application for myself where i can input a website url and get a list of all the cookies the website sets.

Similiar like this site http://www.cookie-checker.com/

How is this possible? What do i need to approach?
I tried to use [HTTP_Request](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request/) but that doesnt' seem the right direction

```
$req = new HTTP_Request($url);
$req->setMethod(HTTP_REQUEST_METHOD_GET);
$req->sendRequest();
$cookies = $req->getResponseCookies();
```

Comment: Check HTTP_Request documentation again. It says you can manage cookies across requets using HTTP_Request2_CookieJar.  That one has an array of stored cookies (from http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request2/docs/latest/HTTP_Request2/HTTP_Request2_CookieJar.html).